# Add new form to Template Library (Object repository) Delphi Xe2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Delphi Xe2 Update 4 Hf 1

1. I create the new form
2. I modify and save
3. On the form I click the right button of the mouse and I choose "Add to Repository", where: "Delphi Files"
4. I close all
5. File, New, Vcl form application - Delphi
6. File, New, Other, Delphi Files: **here I do not see added before the form** :(
7. File, New, Customise, Delphi Files - here I see
8. Tools, Template Libraries, Default (RAD), Properties, Delphi Files - and here I see

[image]

I tried to make changes to file C:\Users\ [mylogin]\Application Data\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\RADStudioRepository.xml (and C:\Program Files (x86) \Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\ObjRepos\en ) but results are not present.
In "manual" at me it has turned out to add the project as it is described here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_Template_Libraries (or this: http://blogs.embarcadero.com/pawelglowacki/2011/11/28/39454)

```
<TemplateLibrary Version="0.1" id="GuTemplateId">
   <Name>Gu Template Library</Name>
   <Description>Gu</Description>
   <Items>
          <Item id="GuProject1" Creator="DelphiProjectRepositoryCreator">
            <Name>GuProject</Name>
            <Description>Standart Gu project</Description>
            <Author>Gu</Author>
            <Icon>Project\GuProject1_Icon.ico</Icon>
        <Projectfile>GuProject1.dproj</Projectfile>
            <DefaultProjectName>GuProject1</DefaultProjectName>
            <FilePath>Project</FilePath>
          </Item>
   </Items>
</TemplateLibrary>
```

*The note: it was long taken with keys < / > and a file .bdsproj which is not created but it is required, both problems has solved*

[image]

And how to insert _ only _ the form and it is desirable in the folder "My" (or at least in Delpfi Files or Other Files)

++
Still: some external components are established: TMS, LMD, DEVExp, Jedy. On a photo it is visible, that some of them have folders or for example in Delphi Files - JCL Exception Dialog. But in xml-files (above) I can not find on their the reference. How it is made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, this looks like a bug. Here's a workaround:

After adding the form to the repository, do the following:
File\New\Customize... find your item, drag and drop it into Menu Items, click OK. This will make the item visible in the "New Items" (File\New\Other...) dialog.

However, it will also add the new item to the top-level menu File\New which may not be what you want. You can go to File\New\Customize... again and drag it out of Menu Items, click OK. The new item will disappear from the top-level menu but it will stay visible in the "New Items" dialog.

I've tried this with Delphi XE2.

Edit: To answer your question, *"How it is made?"* (without using the repository), probably with [OpenTools API](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overview_of_the_Tools_API). [Here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28050)'s a very old article which shows how to create and register your [`IOTAModuleCreator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_Forms_and_Projects) implementation in a design package.